# Regex to replace file paths using replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I'm attempting to change file paths on a html file using groovy. The original path is in the format

```
"C:\\\\git\\\\test\\\\ui\\\\UI_Framework\\\\mochawesome-report\\\\screenshot\\\\assign item to user and verify.png"
```

I would like to change it to

```
"\\\\\\\\share\\\\topics\\\\UI_Testing\\\\ui\\\\V1234567\\\\screenshot\\\\assign item to user and verify.png"
```

I've attempted to use the replaceAll method but it does not seem to have any effect:

```
def reportfile = new File("report.html")
def filetext = reportfile.getText('UTF-8')
def fixlinks = filetext.replaceAll("C:\\\\git\\\\test\\\\ui\\\\UI_Framework\\\\mochawesome-report\\\\screenshot\\\\assign item to user and verify.png", "\\\\\\\\share\\\\topics\\\\UI_Testing\\\\ui\\\\V1234567\\\\screenshot\\\\assign item to user and verify.png")
reportfile.text = fixlinks
```

The file remains unchanged. I know replaceAll method takes regular expressions in the first parameter, how can I modify my search string to find the file path?

Comment: Can't you just say what is added or deleted ? It's killing my eyes trying to pick it out of your verbose, bad fonted strings.

Comment: Sorry I've reformatted the strings in the question

Comment: From the little I can make out, there seems to be a problem with escaping escapes within double quoted strings. I'd check that first. Make a string with the regex, then print it out, see if escapes are stripped. If they are, you have to add escapes. If nothing changes, then ?

Comment: Typically the raw regex is this `(?i)C:\\git\\test\\ui\\UI_Framework\\mochawesome-report\\screenshot\\assign item to user and verify\.png`  Java string quoted is this `"(?i)C:\\\\git\\\\test\\\\ui\\\\UI_Framework\\\\mochawesome-report\\\\screenshot\\\\assign item to user and verify\\.png"` where the replacement is this `"\\\\share\\topics\\UI_Testing\\ui\\V1234567\\screenshot\\assign item to user and verify.png"`